# Confusing regex in PHP codebase

Tags: php, regex

I feel I have a basic understanding of regex but I came across this conditional in our codebase the other day and I can't get my head around it:

```
if ($content && !preg_match('/{\w+}/', $content->title))
```

I was under the impression that the curly braces were min/max ranges and thus the `\w+` doesn't really work inside but it doesn't error.

Currently it is letting through a `$content->title` of `Unsubscribe` which makes sense for our application, but would presumably match `/\w+/`.

Can anyone shed any light on this or should I rewrite it to something more sensible?

Comment: Next time you're confused throw your regex into here: https://regex101.com <- Look at the explanation  on the right side

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, what a great resource

Comment: Pretty stunned that this question has been marked as a duplicate to what is essentially a regex manual. Shall I go over to all the basic MySQL questions and say 'This already has an answer hear' with a link to the MySQL docs homepage? The moderation on this site really annoys me sometimes... luckily I already have the answer I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use characters `{}`,regex engine assumes it as the characters `{` and `}` literally.but when it has a **preceding token** and a number within `{}` it interpreted as [Limiting Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).So the following regex :

```
{\w+}
```

will match character `{` and then any combinations with length 1 or more of word characters then `}`

In One case it returns an error and its when you use a number within `{}` without preceding token.

Comment: Cheers, I think I was looking into it way too deeply! Makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

`{\w+}` break-down:

`{` and `}` matches `{` and `}` literally

`\w+` match any word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

`+` means one or more times

So `{\w+}` will match `{someTextHere}`

Comment: Thanks, very helpful and would have been accepted, but I went for Kasra's answer because it addressed directly the exact issue that had confused me.